# yii2: SqlDataProvider with pagination and searcModel getting error preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

Tags: pagination, yii2, csqldataprovider

i want to show data using sqlDataProvider to gridview from different table and calculate it, here my code in siteController.php 
`public function actionSyahriyah()
    { $searchModel = new SyahriyahSearch();
        $db = Yii::$app->db;
        $bayar = $db ->createCommand('SELECT sy.no_syahriyah, sy.banyak, sa.nama, sy.tgl, sa.tarif 
                                        FROM santri sa, syahriyah sy 
                                        WHERE sa.no_induk = sy.no_induk
                                        ORDER BY sy.tgl');
         $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $bayar,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5 
            ],
        ]);
        return $this->render('syahriyah',[
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }`

and this is the gridview:
     `<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
           // ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'tgl',
            'banyak',
             ], 
        'export' => false,
    ]); 
?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dataProvider

```
<?php

    $bayar = $db ->createCommand('SELECT sy.no_syahriyah, sy.banyak, sa.nama, sy.tgl, sa.tarif 
           FROM santri sa, syahriyah sy 
           WHERE sa.no_induk = sy.no_induk
           ORDER BY sy.tgl');

    $dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
        'sql' => $bayar,
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 5 
            ],
        ],
    ]);

?>
```

Comment: i use your advice, but i got error _preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given_ in SqlDataProvider.php

Comment: I'm sorry but you comment seems not related to the answer  .. i don't see any preg_match .. eventually update you post and show the related code ..

Comment: Looking to your code  You are using a search model  and a dataProvider probalibly not related .. you should try without modelSearch .. and then you should create or exented you modelSearch with an search function the manage the relation you need  .. otherwise you can't use the filter and search functionality.. for show, filter and search data from different table could be useful this link .. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/